# Using Drill Down Starting from the World Map

Tags: jvectormap

today I got interest in the JVectorMap package which is apparently just what I was looking for. However, I have a problem which I could not solve on my own.

I am trying to build a Drill Down map starting at the world level and then drilling down to the country or even to the county level. So I tried just to start with the example code from the JVecorMap package drill-down.html and exchanged the main map by the world_mill_en map.

```
  <script>
    $(function(){
        var map1,
            map2;

        new jvm.MultiMap({
            container: $('#map1'),
            maxLevel: 1,
            mapUrlByCode: function(code, multiMap){
                window.alert('assets/us/jquery-jvectormap-data-'+code.toLowerCase()+'-'+multiMap.defaultProjection+'-en.js');
                return 'assets/us/jquery-jvectormap-data-'+code.toLowerCase()+'-'+multiMap.defaultProjection+'-en.js';
            },
            main: {
                map: 'world_mill_en',
                series: {
                    regions: [{
                        scale: ['#C8EEFF', '#0071A4'],
                        normalizeFunction: 'polynomial',
                        values: {
                            "US-NY": 16.63,
                            "AL": 11.58,
                            "DZ": 158.97,
                            "AO": 85.81,
                            "AG": 1.1,
                            "AR": 351.02
                        }   
                    }]  
                }
            }
        });
    });
  </script>
```

I know of course that the maps I want to drill down to need to be imported before and that they need to be linked correctly within the mapUrlByCode method. I did this, but the drill down does not work: When I click on a country, this country gets zoomed in but no additional county data is loaded. Also, for the US the zoom in doesn't work since the western part of Alaska is on the right edge of the world map.

These are the two problems I am facing. Can somebody help with that?

Sven

Comment: Have you checked the error in your browser console?